# Disable ng-invalid for formGroup

Tags: css, angular

I have a CSS property:

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid:not(form):not(formGroup) {
  border-left: 5px solid #ff5663; /* red */
}
```

that gives me red indicator when form input are not valid.

But I have a case, where my form is a `formArray`:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="competitorForm">
  <div formArrayName="competitors">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let competitor of competitorForm.controls['competitors'].controls; let i = index"
           formGroupName="{{i}}">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class=" form-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-lg" formControlName="firstname" placeholder="First name"
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && competitor.controls.firstname.errors }">
            <div *ngIf="(submitted && competitor.controls.firstname.errors)" class="text-primary">
              <div *ngIf="competitor.controls.firstname.errors.required" translate
                   [translateParams]="{attribute: 'firstname'}">
                validation.required
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I have 2 red left border, one for the field, and 1 for the row

I tried:

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid:not(form):not(formGroup) {
  border-left: 5px solid #ff5663; /* red */
}
```

but it doesn't seems to work. Any idea how can I disable red border for rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `:not(.row)` to your selector if you don't want to display the red border on the div with class row.

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid:not(form):not(formGroup):not(.row) {
  border-left: 5px solid #ff5663; /* red */
}
```

.not css selector docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Looks like also you need to apply :not(.classname) syntax for formGroup case like so:

```
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid:not(form):not(.formGroup):not(.row) {
  border-left: 5px solid #ff5663; /* red */
}
```

Comment: now red border is at formArrayName level, it cover all height of my modal, I will update my code

Comment: added <form> and <div>

Comment: Instead of using :not pseudo selector to remove various multiple uncontrollable cases I would do the class more specific something like: input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {} but you need to pay attention for the rest of your application not to impact negatively in other cases.

Comment: it worked. I don't think it will have side effect! Thanks!

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro: I'm glad if I could help ;) Thank you